# Python Class "Constants" in Dataclasses

Tags: python, constants, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Understanding that the below are not true constants, attempting to follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) I'd like to make a "constant" in my @dataclass in Python 3.7.

```
@dataclass
class MyClass:
    data: DataFrame

    SEED = 8675309  # Jenny's Constant
```

My code used to be:

```
class MyClass:
    SEED = 8675309  # Jenny's Constant

    def __init__(data):
        self.data = data
```

Are these two equivalent in there handling of the seed?  Is the seed now part of the init/eq/hash?  Is there a preferred style for these constants?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

They are the same. `dataclass` ignores unannotated variables when determining what to use to generate `__init__` et al. `SEED` is just an unhinted class attribute.

If you want to provide a type hint for a class attribute, you use `typing.ClassVar` to specify the type, so that `dataclass` won't mistake it for an instance attribute.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    data: DataFrame
    SEED: ClassVar[int] = 8675309
```